# Parabolic slide

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, constrained-dynamics

Can you give a big hint for this problem please?

A material point is released at the end of a track in the form of a vertical arc of parabola $y = x^2$ in $[-1,1]$, the meter is selected as a unit of length. 
We not consider friction to reach the other end of the curve. Calculate the length of the path in second.

I know how to calculate the length of a curve, I have an equivalent to L2 degree in physics but I have no idea to do this problem!

I don't understand you want me to edit my question, is it not clear ?

Comment: What is the acceleration along the arc at a position $x$?

Comment: I think it's $d^2x/dt^2$ but I don't know how I can derivate with the time ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: conservation of energy gives $\frac{1}{2}m (\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2)+mgy(x)=mgy(x_0)$. 
But $\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{dx}{dt}\frac{dy}{dx}$, and $dx=\frac{dx}{dt}dt$. You can use these relations to solve for $\dot{x}$ in terms of $x$, and then your integral of $\frac{dx}{\dot{x}}$ must be your integral of $dt$.

Comment: @Shadock also, since $\dot{x}(x_0)=0$ you'll run into an integral with a singularity at one bound of integration, but it has to be an integrable singularity. If it puts you off too much just take $\dot{x}(x_0)=\varepsilon\to 0$.